# Python-Looping through all files in a folder

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, python-2.x

I need to search a few thousand individual text files within a directory to see how many contain a string.  I need to use python.  Right now I have the following basic code working for one individual file.  I can't figure out the next step: how to loop through the content of each of the individual files in the directory.  Here is what I have:

```
stringtofind = 'FULL TEXT' #enter something between the ''s 
filetolookin = '2013-04-061.txt' #enter the file you want to search

def countif(isthis, infile):
    count = 0
    if isthis in open(infile).read():
        count = 1+count
        return count
    else:
        return count

print countif(stringtofind, filetolookin)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to make sure that you use os.path.walk  check [here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

You just need to provide it the directory you want to search through, and then you can call your function at the inner portion of the loop because you'll have the filename that you need.

Example [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` will allow you to recursively enumerate files in a directory. Once you have the file names use functions in `os.path` to get the file name and extension if you need to filter on those. For the file content, the `re` module will let you use regular expressions to search for a pattern line by line.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use glob module, provided all the files you want to search or 
in one folder/directory.

```
import glob
icount = 0
stringtofind = 'FULL TEXT' 
filetolookin = '2013*.txt' 
g = glob.glob(filetolookin)
for f in g: 
    icount = 0
    for j in open(f):
        j.find(stringtofind) >=0:
            print j
            icount = icount + 1 
            # or whatever you want
    print "File: ", f, "count ", icount
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's perfectly suited to using the [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module in the standard libraries:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

usage = 'Call this with a search string and a list of files to search'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, fileinput
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print usage
        sys.exit()

    search_string = sys.argv[1]
    count = 0

    for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[2:]):
        if search_string in line:
            count += 1

    print count
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complete working script for this question using python 2.7.x

```
import sys
import os
import re


def search_count(str,loc):
    count = 0
    os.chdir(loc)    
    for (thisDir, subsHere, filesHere) in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in filesHere:
            with open(filename,"r") as f:
                content = f.read()
                if re.search(str,content):
                    count += 1
    return count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stringtofind = raw_input('Enter text to search: ')
    pathtolookin = raw_input('Enter path to search: ')

    if sys.platform[:3] == 'win':
        pathtolookin = pathtolookin.replace('\\','/')
    print search_count(stringtofind,pathtolookin)
```